# IIS pages accessible remotely in LAN but not locally on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localhost, iis-7.5

We have a MVC site deployed on IIS 7.5.  At one specific client the site can be browsed from client's pc's (on the local LAN), but not from the local server.

How can we configure the server to browse the pages from it's own IIS?

We have tried:

1. Change the hosts file to include 127.0.0.1
2. Played around with the bindings in IIS to include localhost
3. Flush the DNS
4. Ran nbtstat -R

Not sure what else we can try?

UPDATE: We have managed to install Chrome, and realised that the problem is only with IE. So, the problem is solved for us, but the underlying setting is still unknown.

Comment: I'm using Windows Server 2016 TP, so I'm lounchng my web application  from local http://localhost and from LAN by IP address, are you using DNS server?

Comment: Yes. We've tried with DNS name, localhost and IP address - all of them fail.  The users on the LAN are using the DNS name successfully.

Comment: You've to  setup  virtualhosts and remove 127.0.0.1 it always redirect to hosts himself.

Comment: Thanks Archill. Any link that you can share for setting up the virtual hosts? All that I can find is for Apache servers.

Comment: I call them  virtual  hosts, you're write IIS configuration has other name I'll search and post link here.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SGL5BoMvmM here is vdeo how to  configure websites, Here is propertioes of configuration  websites http://support.simpledns.com/kb/a82/virtual-hosting-with-iis-internet-information-services.aspx and host headers here: http://www.visualwin.com/Host-Header/

Comment: Cameron I have one idea: Try add one website, some simle application and configure it at http://localhost/YourApplicationname if it will accesseble, you can  access it from LAN and throuth your firewall.

Comment: My working structure is (I'm develop on  it) : Windows server 2016 technical prevew, there is MS SQL Server installed on  it,  added IIS Web server role and Visual  studio  installed, in project properties I have chose Local IIS instead of IIS Express and created Virtual Directrory. So under Default Website I have dubdirectories, there are my projects, this projects are accesable from server at https://localgost/myproject and from  LAN at :https://MyServerIP/MyProjectName. sorry for my english.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Will try it and revert back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114232/discussion-between-cameron-castillo-and-archil-labadze).

Comment: Is this Windows Server? How about IEESC - is it enabled? Is this server participating in a domain? Are there any policies about the internet access?

Comment: Yes, it is Windows server and IEEESC is enabled and is part of a domain. And there are policies.

Answer (score 0):

> How can we configure the server to browse the pages from it's own IIS?

Double check ports. Maybe it's simple mistake, and you try connect via http://localhost/ (it's mean default port 80), but on IIS you have configured other port ?

Did you try on different port for example http://localhost:8080 (of course you need setup this port on IIS before) ?

> UPDATE: We have managed to install Chrome, and realised that the problem is only with IE. So, the problem is solved for us, but the underlying setting is still unknown.

If problem is with IE (and no problem with Chrome) that's mean, issue with 'Internet Options -> Security' configuration for IE.

If this settings are too restrictive that you can not be able to lunch site.

Check your settings for 'Local Internet' or you can check/set options under 'Custom Level' (you see that you can set lot of restrictions):

[image]

Comment: Hi - yes we have tried other ports. I also agree that it will be a security setting in IE, but which one?  We have played around so far, and manage to break other things. Luckily there's a reset button.

Comment: Hard to say if I don't see your settings. But look for image above - that's how it's works at my case... Default level for all zones, 'Midium-Low' for 'Local Internet'

Comment: Check also 'Sites' for each zone... Add 'localhost' into 'Sites' in 'Local Internet' and remove from all other zones if any... especially check if you do not have 'localhost' in 'Restrictes Sites'.

Comment: Also you can 'Reset Advenced settings' or 'Reset' all browser on 'Advenced' tab,,,

Comment: Other idea - maybe you have some exception/error in your app that cause problem with IE - lunch console 'F12', refresh page, and check if any info show there.

Also you can turn off 'Show Friendly HTTP error messages' in 'Internet Options -> Advenced -> Browsing' - for me this cause blank page when app has exception, switching off this option helps me to see error code... Don't ask why, I have no idea.

Comment: If this still not help you, then my last idea is 'system policy' - maybe something is restricted on the system level - but I'm not admin and I have no idea where and what you can check, sorry.

Comment: One more idea, maybe IE is lock by firewall ;)

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATE: We have managed to install Chrome, and realised that the problem is only with IE. So, the problem is solved for us, but the underlying setting is still unknown.

This means that, it is problem with the settings in internet options.
Make sure that security settings are medium low or medium high as mentioned by @Lukasz Makowej

Also make sure that you enable active scripting in custom level settings.
if this is disabled, ajax calls will not be working and also make sure javascript is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue on some of my very old IIS installations.  If you set the IP binding to use **All Unassigned**, or add a binding with the IP address 127.0.0.1, it should work.  The reason for this is that Windows and IE may change the IP address of a hostname that matches any IP address that the machine has been assigned to the localhost IP address 127.0.0.1.  For example, if the machine has been assigned the IP address 10.11.12.13, and a hostname resolves to 10.11.12.13, IE may use 127.0.0.1 when it sends the request.  If you have Fiddler installed on the server, you can see the request.

NOTE: Sometimes when changing bindings like this, you need to either completely stop and restart IIS, or reboot, in order for the changes to take effect.  Rebooting is the best choice, if the changes don’t appear to be working properly.